# Attempting to push a child out of a parent, but parent gets a scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to push a child outside of the parent's box, however, it seems that the parent just expands in length and gets a scrollbar, so the child stays inside, and is not visible outside of the parent.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Comment: `.parent{overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj the child gets clipped at the edge of the parent. However, the scrollbar is gone, so I'm halfway there :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add negative position to child: 
Example:

```
left:-20px;
```

Comment: This is what I attempted with "margin-bottom: -20px;", however, the child isn't visible outside of the parent...